# does the order of columns in a SQL select matters?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate

my question is regarding a left join I've tried to count how many people are tracking a certain project.
(there can be zero followers)

now the only way i can get it to work is by adding

```
group by idproject
```

my question is if the is a way to avoid using this and only selecting and implicitly
setting that group option.

**SQL:**

```
select `project_view`.`idproject` AS `idproject`,
count(`track`.`iduser`) AS `c`,`name`
from `project_view` left join `track` using(idproject)
```

I [expected it count null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) as zero but it doesn't appear at all,
 if i neglect counting then it shows as null where there are no followers.

Comment: you need the group by so that the aggregate function knows what to count by.  The order of the selects do not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a WHERE clause to specify a certain project then you **don't** need a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT project_view.idproject, COUNT(track.iduser) AS c, name
FROM project_view
LEFT JOIN track USING (idproject)
WHERE idproject = 4
```

If you want a count for each project then you **do** need a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT project_view.idproject, COUNT(track.iduser) AS c, name
FROM project_view
LEFT JOIN track USING (idproject)
GROUP BY idproject
```

Comment: this is what I did, I thought that i could accomplish a similar behaviour without using "group by" explicitly. now i understand the problem with it

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order of selecting matters. For performance reasons you (typically) want your most limiting select first to narrow your data set. This makes every subsequent query operate on a smaller dataset.

Comment: while this can be true but it does relate to my question, thanks for the tip anyway.